# Change in NAL_REF_IDC value for P frames in x264 encoding

Tags: encoder, x264

By changing nal_ref_idc value from 2 to 0 for all P frames in x264 encoding, I have observed the size of the P frames gets changed. Is it because of all P frames are now only referenced to a single I frame in GOP?

But the size of the first P frame after I frame should be independent of both the situation (whether direct encoding, nal_ref_idc = 0 or cumulative encoding, nal_ref_idc = 2), but I am getting a change of size in first P frame also after the I frame. Can anyone please tell me the possible reason or explanation behind this?